# How to control JpaRepository for similar query

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I made an entity as below.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Lecture {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 4096)
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 4096)
    private String link;


    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    private boolean visible;
}
```

And I used jpa repository.

```
public interface LectureRepository extends JpaRepository<Lecture, Integer> {
    Page<LectureList> findByVisible(boolean visible, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And this is filter for list.

```
public interface LectureList {
    String getTitle();

    LocalDateTime getLink();

    Integer getId();

}
```

So when I get return data by findByVisible query, it gives "id, title, link" without a problem.
But I need other filter for another client. 
For example, another repository should give me "id, title" field. 
So I think I have to make another Repository File for this case. 
Could I have a more simple solution for this? Could I make this query in the same repository file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. You can have [different functions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#:%7E:text=2.3.2%20query%20creation) in the same JPA Repository interface. And you can only have one Repository per Entity.

There are different solutions to present different information through the controller itself. If you still want to show all objects in a Page you can create another object with the parameters you'd like to return, for example.